# Improve logic for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I have this method from which I'll check provider and uid  attributes to choose between creating a new register or take an existing one.
THis is to integrate facebook login into my app. 
What would be a good logic if I want to check for users that already have been registered in my app, just not through facebook, using their email address as search key and then addding to that account the proivider and uid attributes from facebook?

```
def self.from_omniauth(hash) 
    where(provider: hash.provider, uid: hash.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = hash.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.username = hash.info.name
end
```

---

updates

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

```
 def facebook

    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

I updated the code as you suggested with the method

```
def self.from_omniauth(hash)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(hash.provider, hash.uid) || find_by_omni_email(hash.info.email) || create_with_omniauth(hash)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(hash)
    u = User.new
    u.provider = hash.provider
    u.uid = hash.uid
    u.email = hash.info.email
    u.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    u.username = hash.info.name

    puts "tried to create_with+omniauth"
  end

  def self.find_by_omni_email(email)
    User.where(email: email).first

    puts "ran find_by_omni_email"


  end

  def self.find_by_provider_and_uid(provider, uid)
    User.where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first

    puts "ran find_by_provider_and_uid"
  end
```

Comment: This line: `where(provider: hash.provider, uid: hash.uid).first_or_create` will not create any new record if the user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

change your logic this way. it will check for all scenarios

```
def self.from_omniauth(hash)
  find_by_provider_and_uid(hash.provider, hash.uid) || find_by_omni_email(hash.info.email) || create_with_omniauth(hash)
end

def self.create_with_omniauth(hash)
  u = User.new
  u.provider = hash.provider
  u.uid = hash.uid
  u.email = hash.info.email
  u.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  u.username = hash.info.name
  u.save
  u
end

def self.find_by_omni_email(email)
  User.where(email: email).first
end
```

#this method below active record provides by default. i added incase if it doesnot or there is some change

```
def self.find_by_provider_and_uid(provider, uid)
  User.where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first
end
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how this code works. Say find_by_provider_and_uid doesn't find  the register, what is actually returned  from User.where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first ?
Is it a boolean (false?)  that then makes find_by_omni_email run? 
In that case if finds an account don't I need a code that will add into that account the provider and the uid values?

Comment: first it will find the user by provider and uid. if it finds. it will be returned as user. if not it will try to find by email if it finds by email that user will be returned. when both `find_by_provider_and_uid`, `find_by_omni_email` dont return anything it will call `create_with_omniauth` and create a user and returns.

Comment: if no user is found by  User.where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first ? it will return nil

Comment: I tried your code and it seemed to work fine but I ran into this problem

Comment: undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    puts "puts " + @user.to_s
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

Comment: can you share from where are you calling.? and i also updated my method create_with_omniauth when i last commented. so im sure you are using updated code. please share controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83726/discussion-between-athar-and-vinibol12).